# Send SQL Email (href with colum)

Tags: sql, email, hyperlink, href

I want to link the word Click with URL in the email. This URL change for every row of SELECT.

I write this:

```
td = CAST('<a href="'+REPLACE('http://asñdjas/asdas/sadas.aspx?lng=&orig=&guid={ID}','{ID}',T.projectId)+'">Click</a>' AS XML), ''
```

But SQL server return:

> Análisis de XML: línea 1, carácter 73; se esperaba punto y coma

Which translates to

> XML parsing : line 1 , character 73; expected semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` symbol should be encoded as `&amp;`. The parser sees &orig and expects a semicolon after it (or at least at some point in the string).